# Making anonymous functions easily distinguishable

Tags: lambda, common-lisp

I'd like to add some metadata to a class of anonymous functions to make them easy to identify. So far all of my ideas are hackish or doubtful:

A plist item would work, but apparently it's only for symbols, not lambdas.

I could insert something in the docstring:

```
(lambda (x) "is-special" ...
```

But that seems really ugly, or:

```
(lambda (x)
  (if 
   (eq x 'special) 
   t
   ...
```

Even uglier.

Is there a not-so-badly-hackish way to set an attribute on a function object?

I could also use the type system to distinguish my functions:

Placing the function in a structure or CLOS object is possible, but feels cumbersome.

Is it possible to create lambdas that are a custom subtype of the function type?

Can CLOS objects be made to act as executable functions? I'm thinking of something similar to python's **call** attribute.

Comment: Regarding your last question, on an implementation that has MOP (meta-object protocol), you can use the [`funcallable-standard-class`](http://www.alu.org/mop/dictionary.html) and specialize [`print-object`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pr_obj.htm) for your purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: A quick-and-dirty option, if your implementation prints the name of `flet` or `labels` functions:

```
(defmacro nlambda (name (&rest lambda-list) &body body)
  `(labels ((,name (,@lambda-list)
              ,@body))
     #',name))
```

Keep reading if you need to reliably print the function name.

---

One example that follows your last question, assuming your Common Lisp implementation follows the metaobject protocol (MOP):

```
(defclass funcallable-object ()
  ((name :initarg :name :initform nil :accessor funcallable-name)
   (function :initarg :function :initform nil :accessor funcallable-function)
  (:metaclass mop:funcallable-standard-class))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((object funcallable-object) &key function &allow-other-keys)
  (setf (funcallable-function object) function))

(demethod (setf funcallable-function) :after (function (object funcallable-object))
  (mop:set-funcallable-instance-function object (or function #.(constantly nil))))

(defmethod print-object ((object funcallable-object) stream)
  (print-unreadable-object (object stream :type t :identity t)
    (with-slots (name) object
      (when name
        (write name stream)))))
```

Note that you must replace the `mop` package name according to your implementation, or if you use cl-mop.

---

EDIT: Here are a few ways you could use it.

Directly:

```
(make-instance 'funcallable-object
  :name 'foo
  :function #'(lambda (<args>)
                <body>))
```

With a macro:

```
(defmacro nlambda (name (&rest lambda-list) &body body)
  `(labels ((,name (,@lambda-list)
              ,@body))
     (make-instance 'funcallable-object
       :name ',name
       :function #',name)))

(nlambda foo (<args>)
  <body>)
```

I used `labels` in the examples instead of `flet`, because I believe a named lambda's greater utility is its ability to recurse.

Answer (score 3):

I don't known enough MOP yet to answer your last questions, but I can suggest you a hackish way to do what you want.

You could declare a special variable to keep track of the lambdas to which you have added meta-data: `(defvar *annotated-lambdas* (make-hash-table))`.

Then define a function to get/set lambdas from it.

```
(defun get-lambda (lambda &optional (annotated-lambdas *annotated-lambdas*))
  (gethash lambda annotated-lambdas))

(defun (setf get-lambda) (annotation lambda &optional (annotated-lambdas *annotated-lambdas*))
  (setf (gethash lambda annotated-lambdas) annotation))
```

Now you can already test something:

```
(let ((l (lambda (x) (1+ x))))
  (setf (get-lambda l) "Add one."))
```

At this point `*annotated-lambdas*` should already have an element in it.

Now you can use a little macro to make this less cumbersome:

```
(defmacro lambda* ((&rest args) (annotation &optional (annotated-lambdas *annotated-lambdas*)) &body body)
  (let ((name (gensym)))
`(let ((,name (lambda (,@args)
        ,@body)))
   (setf (get-lambda ,name ,annotated-lambdas) ,annotation))))
```

Which you can use like this:

```
(lambda* (x) ("Add one.")
  (+1 x))
```

Of course, to have access to the annotation, you need to have access to the lambda, which I assume you do because otherwise you would have use a function (which is simply a symbol pointing to a lambda).
Also the "annotation" can be anything, a string, a list, an alist, a plist or even an hash-table.

Comment: Right. Typically one uses non-standard weak hash-tables for that. That way unreferenced functions can get GCed...

Comment: @RainerJoswig Could you elaborate a bit, it sounds interesting.

Comment: @Sharpie, implementations have non-standard support for weak hash tables (e.g. [ABCL](http://abcl.org/trac/browser/trunk/abcl/src/org/armedbear/lisp/make-hash-table.lisp), [Allegro CL](http://franz.com/support/documentation/9.0/doc/implementation.htm#cl-make-hash-table-2), [CLisp](http://clisp.sourceforge.net/impnotes/weak.html#weak-ht), [Clozure CL](http://ccl.clozure.com/docs/ccl.html#weak-references), [LispWorks](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/LW/html/lw-654.htm#pgfId-1039790) and [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Hash-Table-Extensions)) to allow entries to be GC'ed.

Answer (score 3):

If it's for printing, I would just do this:

```
CL-USER 8 > (flet ((foo (a b) (+ a b))) #'foo)
#<interpreted function FOO 40600008E4>

CL-USER 9 > (defmacro nlambda (name &rest rest)
              `(flet ((,name ,@rest))
                 (function ,name)))
NLAMBDA

CL-USER 10 > (mapcar (lambda (x) (nlambda foo (y) (+ x y))) '(1 2 3 4))
(#<interpreted function FOO 4060000B54>
 #<interpreted function FOO 4060000B84>
 #<interpreted function FOO 4060000BB4>
 #<interpreted function FOO 4060000BE4>)
```

If you want to get the name back, you can use `FUNCTION-LAMBDA-EXPRESSION`, if your implementation and compiler settings allow it. Here I use LispWorks. The third value is the name:

```
CL-USER 30 > (flet ((foo (a b) (+ a b))) #'foo)
#<interpreted function FOO 406000183C>

CL-USER 31 > (nth-value 2 (function-lambda-expression *))
FOO
```

For another approach see: [pretty function](https://github.com/nallen05/pretty-function).

Comment: There's no way to get at that name programmatically is there? That would work nicely. It's not for printing.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the [pretty-function](https://github.com/nallen05/pretty-function) library which may be what you are looking for. It is available through quicklisp.